# Is there a way to send two files with different keys using form data with postman?

Tags: node.js, request, postman, multipartform-data, form-data

I am using postman and want to set two different files with different keys in the request.

I have a node.js project where I am using `multer()` module for getting the files from the request.
But I can not find a way how can I get the two files with different keys.

```
multer().array('file1');
```

This does not work for my case.

Is there a way I can manage to get the files in a way that I mentioned?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.

From the documentation:
*Accept a mix of files, specified by fields. An object with arrays of files will be stored in req.files.*

*fields should be an array of objects with name and optionally a maxCount. Example:*

```
[
      { name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 },
      { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }
]
```

In my case:

```
 [
        { name: 'file1', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'file2', maxCount: 1 }
    ]
```